# PowerShell: Removing users from specified groups

Tags: powershell, foreach, import-csv

Edit:
Based on input from Scepticalist and TheStingPilot, I have cobbled together the following:

```
$users = import-csv usersfromgroups.csv
Foreach ($user in $users){
    remove-adgroupmember -identity "$users.group" -members $users.username -WhatIf
}
```

This returns the following:

```
remove-adgroupmember : Cannot find an object with identity: '           .group' under: 'DC=domain,DC=com'.
At line:3 char:5
+     remove-adgroupmember -identity "$users.group" -members $users.use ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (           .group:ADGroup) [Remove-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADGroupMember
```

I'm not really sure how to proceed. Again, any help would be appreciated.

---

Original question:

I have a list of thirty or so users to be removed from a number of groups. Each user is to be removed from specific groups, and what groups they are to be removed from vary from user to user. I do not have a test environment. I have the list in CSV format, and it looks something like this:

```
username,group
User1,Group1
User1,Group2
User1,Group3
User2,Group4
User2,Group1
User3,Group2
User4,Group5
```

I've cobbled together the following, which doesn't look quite right to me:

```
$users = import-csv usersfromgroups.csv
$groups = import-csv usersfromgroups.csv
Foreach ($user in $users){
    remove-adgroupmember -identity "$group" -members $user.username -Confirm:$true
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$users = import-csv usersfromgroups.csv` content will be an object, import it once and access members using the property names e.g. `$users.username` and `$users.group`.

Comment: If you want to test, use -WhatIf parameter.

Comment: Thanks both; I've gotten further, but not all the way. See the updated question for details.

Comment: You are iterating the collection with `Foreach ($user in $users){..}`, but inside the loop you do not use the **single** iterating variable `$user`, but the whole collection `$users` (**plural**). In the second code you refer to a `$group` which is not defined. Try `Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $user.group -Members $user.username -WhatIf`

Comment: That nets me a slightly different error:

remove-adgroupmember : Cannot find an object with identity: '@{username=User1; group=Group1}.group' under: 'DC=domain,DC=com'.
At line:3 char:5
+     remove-adgroupmember -identity "$user.group" -members $users.user ...

Comment: When evaluating group and user separately, I got it to work. I'll post the working script as an answer to this question. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on suggestions from the thread, I've got a script that works, assuming that your CSV contains the group in which the specified user is a member. If the user is a member of a group contained in the specified group, it doesn't work, but that is an issue for another day.

```
$users = import-csv usersfromgroups.csv
Foreach ($user in $users){
$group = Get-AdGroup $user.group 

  remove-adgroupmember -identity $group -members $users.username #-WhatIf
}
```