# Powershell: Remove user from all membergroups of a specified group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

TL;DR: I have a CSV-formatted list of users ~500 and ~ 200 access groups from which they must be removed. The access groups generally do not contain users, but rather user groups, and I need a way to find the group that gives the users the access specified, and then remove it.

This is a follow-up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74359369/powershell-removing-users-from-specified-groups/74361723#74361723). As I noted, the solution will not work if the user is a member of a group other than the one specified. This makes perfect sense, but means that the script doesn't actually work terribly well for my use case. Let me explain:

The client's setup is to have an access group (scope: Domain Local) that provides permissions to a given resource (e.g. a network share), and a user group (scope: Global) that contains the users that have access. In many cases, groups are nested much like russian nesting dolls, and the worst example I've seen has six levels of nesting. (Yes, this should be addressed, but that is outside the scope of this question.)

Ideally, the groups would have names that are identical other than their prefix, like so:

- Access group: AG
- User group: UG

Unfortunately, naming of these groups has historically been less than consistent. The result is that I can't simply change the prefix and trust that the result is correct. What's more, even if this weren't the case, the nesting dolls issue means that I might not find all the groups that grants a user access to a specific resource.

Had the issue been the reverse, I could have used get-adgroupmember with the -recursive parameter - which, in fact, is how the list was originally assembled.

My hunch is that I need to reverse my original script, starting with the AD group, rather than the user account, but I'm really not sure how to proceed from there.

Edit: A colleague suggested modifying my original script as follows:

```
$users = import-csv usersfromgroups.csv
Foreach ($user in $users){
$group = Get-ADGroupMember $user.group | Get-ADGroup

  remove-adgroupmember -identity $group -members $users.username #-WhatIf
}
```

That returned the following.

```
Get-ADGroup : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=User Name,OU=OU1,OU=OU2,DC=OU3,DC=OU4' under: 'DC=OU3,DC=OU4'.
At line:3 char:42
+ $group = Get-ADGroupMember $user.group | Get-ADGroup
+                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=USER,DC=OU3,DC=OU4:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroup], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup
 
Remove-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
At line:5 char:34
+   remove-adgroupmember -identity $group -members $users.username #-Wh ...
+                                  ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADGroupMember>
```

The CSV looks something like this (though entirely anonymized):

```
username,group
User1,Group1
User1,Group2
User1,Group3
User2,Group4
User2,Group1
User3,Group2
User4,Group5
```

Comment: Do you have two input lists: one list of 500 users and another list of 200 groups from which all of those users must be removed? Or do you have a list of users that also includes the groups they must be removed from, and some users will not be removed from some groups that others will be removed from?

Comment: I'll be adding an example of the CSV in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that `Get-ADGroupMember $user.group` returns a User which then the Piped `Get-ADGroup` cant process leading to the $group variable being undefined/null which intern leads to the error:

```
Remove-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
At line:5 char:34
+   remove-adgroupmember -identity $group -members $users.username #-Wh ...
+                                  ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADGroupMember>
```

Not sure if this is correct but trying to help