# Powershell to remove disabled users from specific Azure group only

Tags: azure, powershell, csv, office365

please can you help. I need something a little like this:
[PowerShell: Removing users from specified groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74359369/powershell-removing-users-from-specified-groups)

but I need it to only to target only one specific group, not multiple. I'm not that confident with creating a script from scratch.

If it helps I have got the disabled users in a .csv ready to go.

So far I can find many resources to remove disabled users from all Azure or AD groups, but nothing for specific groups. Also, I am a bit pushed for time/nervous about creating a script that could remove active users.

TIA

I tried the aforementioned solution to remove deactivated users from all azure groups, but this is large org where there are many many groups and this will take too long. For now at least, this one group is a priority. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the users that must be removed from a specific group in a csv file, you could have a Powershell script like this

```
$users = import-csv your-csv-file.csv
$adGroup = 'my-group'
foreach ($user in $users) {
    Remove-AdGroupMember -Identity $adGroup -Members $user #-WhatIf
}
```

Please remove the `#` in front of the -WhatIf to check what would happen if the cmdlet runs, that way you can see which users would be removed from the $adGroup

I hope this helps

Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74361723/4317508